# Why img doesn't load in actionscript?

Tags: apache-flex, image, actionscript, flex4

I would like to display an Image using a Bitmap as source. I've been suggested something akin to this but somehow it still doesn't work.

img1 works fine... But img2 doesn't load for some reason.

```
private function onComplete(event:Event):void{
    _bytes = event.target.data;

    img1.source = _bytes;  /*this last bit works*/

    _bmpData = new BitmapData(img1.width,img1.height);

    _bmpData.draw(img1,new Matrix());

    _bmp = new Bitmap(_bmpData);

    img2.source=_bmp;
}
```

Comment: What kind of objects are img1 and img2? I don't know what object has the property .source but I'm guessing your problem is simply that img2.source is supposed to be the BitmapData rather than the Bitmap.

Comment: Just regular Spark Image... I changed my code so that `img2.source` receives the BitmapData rather than the Bitmap, but still no go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`img2.source=_bmp;` doesn't work because you can't pass a Bitmap object to the source property of an Image control.  From the [documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/SWFLoader.html#source):

> The value of the source property represents a relative or absolute URL; a ByteArray representing a SWF, GIF, JPEG, or PNG; an object that implements IFlexDisplayObject; a class whose type implements IFlexDisplayObject; or a String that represents a class.

A Bitmap is a DisplayObject, but it does not implement IFlexDisplayObject, so instead of using `Image.source` you can add the Bitmap as a child of the Image:

```
img2.addChild(_bmp);
```

Comment: Hmm... when I try and do that, I get : `addChild() is not available in this class. Instead, use addElement() or modify the skin, if you have one.` at Runtime. At compile-time, there's no errors.

Comment: I changed it from Spark to Halo Image but still same results... nothing happens... But the error message I got (see above) didn't show up though.

Comment: Sorry, I was looking at mx, not Spark. Try making _img2 a BitmapImage instance instead.  Then you should be able to pass a Bitmap to it's source property as you were doing originally.

Comment: Well.. I didn't exactly use the solution you gave me but you've pointed me to the right direction.. in case you're interested, my final code is this: http://pastie.org/2430499

Comment: @Felipe - you should post that as a separate answer, and in 2 days you'll be allowed to mark it correct.